# Como alterar um arquivo HTML por outro?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho os arquivos:

- h1.html
- h2.html
- start.html

**Start.html:**

```
<frameset cols='20%, *'>
<frame src='h1.html' name='menu'>
<frame src='h2.html' name='resto'>
</frameset>
```

Gostaria de saber de que maneira posso alterar, por exemplo, um texto do arquivo `h1.html` utilizando um botão no arquivo `h2.html`.

Comment: Tu pode passar a variável por post e o texto será a variável recebido caso ela exista, vc faz isso usando o php e o html

Comment: Por que está utilizando `frame` e `frameset`? Ps.: Ambos estão deprecado.

Comment: @Valdemir sou iniciante, mas fazer o que estou em um mesmo html será cansativo e desorganizado. Woton Sampaio dê um exemplo, nunca usei php xD

Comment: @Raptador Realmente não estou conseguindo nem com o `contentDocument`, o navegador está bloqueando o acesso, removi a resposta enquanto procuro uma solução :) Uma dúvida. Você utiliza jQuery?

Comment: tenho importado, mas não sei utilizar sozinho, se tiver um código pronto agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos supor para o seu exemplo a seguinte estrutura:

```
start.html
   h1.html (iframe menu)
       function alterarInput()...
   h2.html (iframe resto)
       <input id="input1" />
```

Em qualquer dos `iframes`, você pode acessar a página *parent* (start) com `Javascript`, e em seguida qualquer elemento da página *parent*, incluindo os `iframes`. Então, no exemplo que coloquei na *function* que está no `iframe` menu, vamos acessar o `input` do `iframe` resto assim:

```
function alterarInput() {
   parent.resto.document.getElementById('input1').value= 'novo valor';
}
```

Obs.: evite usar `iframes`, eles estão obsoletos e as permissões de alguns navegadores podem fazer com que não funcionem. Se precisar usar arquivos separados existem outras alternativas mais modernas.

Comment: creio q o código teria funcionado, o navegador bloqueou o frame de acessar o outro pois tem origem "cross-origin". se existir alguma maneira de definir a origem do arquivo funcionaria

Comment: sim, o código funciona, mas no seu caso não será possível mesmo, restrições de segurança do browser. De qualquer forma, usar `iframe` já é algo obsoleto, e ainda de domínios diferentes? Definitivamente não é uma boa prática